# Request to add a tag synonym or rename - safety-capacitor for x-capacitor

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup, tag-synonyms

Ok, right now we have a single tag for dealing with safety caps and that is x-capacitor.

But there is at least three types that I know of, X, Y and XY capacitors.

When I went to ask a question about the usage of them in a circuit, it was not obvious to me that the tag that I should have used was x-capacitor, but I did look for safety-capacitor, which of course does not exist.

And from just a little bit of searching, it looks like I'm not the only one.  Here are just a couple of questions that would have used the safety-capacitor tag, but instead had to settle for some else.

[What is an "XY" rated safety capacitor, exactly?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333029/what-is-an-xy-rated-safety-capacitor-exactly)  -- tags: safety capacitor

[How safety capacitor replaces optocoupler](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/455754/how-safety-capacitor-replaces-optocoupler)  -- tags: safety capacitor

[Safety Capacitor Selection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/400567/safety-capacitor-selection)  -- tags: capacitor

[Replacing a safety capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417570/replacing-a-safety-capacitor)  -- tags: capacitor

All of the above questions would more than likely have used the tag safety-capacitor if it had existed.  I consider that to be a safe bet considering that safety-capacitor is in title.

The x-capacitor tag has only been used 5 times.  I'm not sure of the exact number of questions that contain the phrase 'safety capacitor' in the title, but its much, much greater than that!

Does anyone have a good reason NOT to just rename that tag?

Comment: Please consider tagging this with the [meta-tag:tag-cleanup] tag, the [meta-tag:tag-synonyms] tag or the [meta-tag:tags] tag. Most requests of this nature would have 1 or more of those tags present